# Grouping .pkl files into lists based on filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have Data sets of .pkl files from 1 to 10 going:

Data1.1, Data1.2, Data1.3 all the way to Data10.1, Data10.2...

Is there a way to collect all the .1s, .2s, .3s together in lists based on the file name?
The number of files is variable so currently I'm up to 10.37 but this could increase.

This would give me a .1 List, a .2 List, etc.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Basically, you should use `os.listdir()` to get a list of the files in a given directory and 'filter' the read filenames as desired using e.g. `str.endswith()` or even a regex. Then you can create new lists based on the 'filtered' items. Adapting this approach with `str.split()` (if not using a regex for filtering) could make list generation more dynamic...

Comment: Currently I've been initialising all the lists manually then searching through the directory to see if the file name matches (as you've mentioned with an ends with() type approach), but now I've got to 30+ lists its becoming incredibly messy and I assumed there would be a better solution to group all these based on the filenames.